# Spring JPA - Error Hibernate on MySQL database creating Foreing Keys

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot with JPA and My-SQL connector to connect to my db. I am using the persisntance from Hibernates to create the tables and to query. But when I create an relation between to Models (Entities), the Hibernate is unable to create the foreign keys in my database, giving the following error.

```
2020-05-16 23:22:43.923  WARN 20752 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table states_cities add constraint FK1h5qj8huxmdulcb6eqo9b366b foreign key (state_id) references states (id)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table states_cities add constraint FK1h5qj8huxmdulcb6eqo9b366b foreign key (state_id) references states (id)" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) [spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.PiIiiApiMvpApplication.main(PiIiiApiMvpApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: REFERENCES command denied to user 'user'@'192.168.99.1' for table 'pi_db.states'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: One thing you can do is  add property 'spring.jpa.show-sql=true' , copy the queries and try to run them against the  DB directly, and start debugging form there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Database user doesn't have the alter table permissions.

```
GRANT ALTER ON tableName TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

use this command to get those permissions